# how to autoscroll to the bottom after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to scroll to the bottom after one submits the form. I have tried different js solutions, including the one in the code, yet none works for me. after the form is submitted, it is redirected back to itself. I did not understand if this was overridding the scrolling function. can someone help please?
the code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php session_start()?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            .show {color: green; border: 1px solid cyan; border-radius: 15px; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-style: halvetica; font-size: 16px;}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">CAS Website</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 well">
        <h3 class="text-primary">Login And Registration</h3>
        <hr style="border-top:1px dotted #ccc;"/>
        <a href="login.php">Already a member? Log in here...</a>
        <br style="clear:both;"/><br />
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="POST" action="save_member.php">   
                <div class="alert alert-info">Registration</div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone-number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email-Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"  class="form-control" required="required"/></br>
                </div>
                <div class="show">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="show()">  Show Password<br>
                </div>
                <script>
                function show() {
                  var show = document.getElementById('password');
                  if (show.type === "password") {
                    show.type = "text";
                  } else {
                    show.type = "password";
                  }
                }
                function godown ()
                        { document.getElementById("down").scrollIntoView(); // JUMP TO DIV "DOWN".
                                }
                </script>
                <?php
                    if($_SESSION['success']){
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" id="down"><?php echo $_SESSION['success'];?></div>
                <?php
                    $_SESSION['success']="";
                    }
                ?>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="register" onclick="godown()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Register</button>
                <?php
                    if(($_SESSION['error'])){
                ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $_SESSION['error'];?></div>
                <?php
                    $_SESSION['error']="";
                    }
                ?>
                <?php
                    if(($_SESSION['notmet'])){
                ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $_SESSION['notmet'];?></div>
                <?php
                    $_SESSION['notmet']="";
                    }
                ?>
                <?php
                    if(($_SESSION['notsame'])){
                ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $_SESSION['notsame'];?></div>
                <?php
                    $_SESSION['notsame']="";
                    }
                ?>
            </form> 
        </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just to clarify, do you mean you don't want the page to refresh and rather scroll down?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use AJAX / Promise calls to submit the form and then use the js function scroll to the bottom when successful. Some thing like this:

```
    fetch('https://myapiserver.com/v1/').then(response => 
        response.json()).then((data(=> {
           callScrollFunction();
    });
```